# predict functions after clogit in R using survival package

Tags: r, survival, stata, clogit

I have difficulties understanding the different types of prediction after running `survival::clogit` in R. I do not think this is due to author's fault, but mainly due to my limited understanding of statistics.

So, I wish someone can enlighten me how the predictions were calculated.

Noted: The data (modified) and my questions are related to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329585/how-to-get-fitted-values-from-clogit-model?answertab=active#tab-top

QUESTION 1:

For example to predict the linear prediction:

With these data:

```
set.seed(1)
sim_data <- data.frame(Used = rep(c(1,0,0,0),1250),
                   Open = round(runif(5000,0,50),0),
                   Strata = rep(1:1250,each=4))
```

Which I run `survival::clogit`

```
mod_sim <- clogit(Used ~ Open + strata(Strata), data = sim_data)
summary(mod_sim)
```

I would get the value for linear prediction as below:

```
head(predict(mod_sim, type = 'lp')) 

    1            2            3            4 
 0.037724631  0.020958128 -0.006986043 -0.051696716 
    5            6 
 0.066367406 -0.031437192
```

In Stata, if I run the post-estimation command and specify *linear prediction* I will get different values as shown below:

```
-.0363274, -.0530939, -.0810381, -.1257488, -.0279442, -.1257488
```

I can see that in Stata, the value for the first observation is calculated from -.0027944*13 (for 1st observation)

QUESTION 2:

Can anyone show me how to calculate different types of prediction for example `term`, `risk` and `expected`

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue as the predict command also doesn't work out of the box. I think this is a question for stackoverflow though, no? Your statistics question is answered below?

Answer (score 2):

The conditional logistic regression model conditions out an intercept for each stratum, so the linear predictor is only determined up to a stratum-specific offset.  Stata uses zero for this offset; R uses the stratum mean of the covariate (for numerical stability)

So

```
> m<-with(sim_data, ave(Open, Strata))
> head(predict(mod_sim, type = 'lp'))
           1            2            3            4            5            6 
 0.037724631  0.020958128 -0.006986043 -0.051696716  0.066367406 -0.031437192 
> head(with(sim_data, coef(mod_sim)*(Open-m) ))
[1]  0.037724631  0.020958128 -0.006986043 -0.051696716  0.066367406 -0.031437192
```

You get `type="risk"` just by exponentiating these

With `type="terms"` the default centering is at the sample mean (`mod_sim$means`) rather than the stratum mean.

```
> head(with(sim_data, coef(mod_sim)*(Open-mod_sim$means) ))
[1]  0.03314235  0.01637584 -0.01156833 -0.05627900  0.04152560 -0.05627900
> head(predict(mod_sim, type = 'terms'))
         Open
1  0.03314235
2  0.01637584
3 -0.01156833
4 -0.05627900
5  0.04152560
6 -0.05627900
```

With `type="expected"` you're computing an absolute risk, so the intercept for each stratum has to be estimated (and the predictions aren't all that useful, since they are only for the observed strata)

The documentation for this is under `?predict.coxph` because `clogit` uses the relationship to the Cox model for computation

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the predict() function, so I won't be able to tell you what this function is doing. However, it is not too difficult to predict probabilities in a clogit-type of model. Once you've estimated your model, you can now use the estimates to compute the proba of each event to occur. For each observation, simply multiply your matrix of predictors (X) with the vector of estimates (B). Then predict the proba as: exp(XB) / sum_j(exp(XB)).

What are you trying to predict? Predicted proba can be negative - If "linear prediction" refers to the linear proba model (basically you forget about the 0/1 nature of your dependent variable) then it sounds like a bad idea.